# How can I create a ScrollView in AndEngine

Tags: android, scrollview, andengine

I need to implement a ScrollView in part of my SimpleBaseGameActivity, but I searched a lot and didn't find anything about this.

How Can I put for example ScrollView of pictures, TextView in the specific part of my SimpleBaseGameActivity ???

Observation: I'm trying to use a Gmail to connect in Andengine forum but, I'm not getting results.

In my code I putted a lot of Texture etc., it works correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is for baseGameActivity.But you can use it also for SimpleBaseGameActivity
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/menu-scroll-example-t5740.html